# How to release memory associated by CGImageCreateWithImageInRect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect()` for generating a small image from a background image runtime, which is going to displayed for every thread call (0.01 sec). Once I start showing part of image through `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` application starts consuming memory in very high rate and crashes within seconds. Memory consumed goes to 20+ MB and crashes. Normal application would run on 2MBs.

```
Image1 = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imageRef, CGRectMake(x, y, w, h));
```

and after processing I do

```
CGImageRelease(Image1);
```

but it is not helping me.

I want to know how to release memory associated with `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect`.

Comment: what's imageRef? can you post more code?

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is in fact CGImageRelease; the pair of lines you have excerpted from your code are correctly balanced. You must be leaking somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, that pair of lines are not balanced, since CGImageCreateWithImageInRect() retains the original image. It should be…

```
CGImageRef Image1 = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imageRef, CGRectMake(x, y, w, h));
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
...
CGImageRelease(Image1);
```

Comment: No. If the new imageRef retains it, that will release it at appropriate time as well.